# Error: attribute 'width' in tag 'amp-img' is set to the invalid value '”2299”'

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm trying to get the WordPress blog portion of my website AMP compliant.  I'm using the "AMP by Automattic" plugin to assist.

The Google Search Console is saying "Invalid layout property found in AMP tag".  The exact error message is: >The attribute 'width' in tag 'amp-img' is set to the invalid value '”2299”'<.

The error relates to the feat-img.

As I copy & paste the GSC error code in and review the source code for a sample webpage, I noticed that the quotation marks around the 2299 are "curly" marks and that they are both right-hand side marks.  (Unfortunately the curly marks do not seem to be showing up in stackoverflow text here).

Could the "curly" marks (presumably added in by the WordPress plug-in) be causing the error?

I originally thought AMP may have had a maximum image size (there appears to be a minimum), but googling didn't confirm that.

Suggestions for how to fix the problem?

Comment: To fix the issue, use regular double quotes, not fancy unicode ones.

Comment: Thanks, but it is someone else's WordPress plug-in.  I was hoping someone could confirm that the unicode quotes would throw an error in AMP before I asked the plug-in author to correct the issue.